# WebLogic: what does "No archive for deployment" mean?

Tags: weblogic12c, netbeans-8

I have for some time been developing Java EE applications against Glassfish, so I have some udnerstanding of application servers. Today I installed WebLogic 12.2, created a data source (it works), configured a new server in NetBeans (version 8.2) to my WebLogic domain (also works).

I then created a new web application by creating Entities from a few database tables, and JSF pages from entity classes; when I delpoy this I get:

```
...
compile:
compile-jsps:
/root/projects/test/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1045: Deployment error: No archive for deployment
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

I can't see any errors in any log files under the domain (but then I'm not sure exactly what to look for) - so, where should I look? And what does the error message actually mean?

===EDIT===

Versions:

```
Java:
# java -version
java version "1.8.0_191"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)

Java EE:
Java EE 7 Web

Weblogic:
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 838986083 Nov  2 11:46 fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls_Disk1_1of1.zip

NetBeans:
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201609300101)
Updates: NetBeans IDE is updated to version NetBeans 8.2 Patch 2
Java: 1.8.0_11; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.11-b03
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_11-b12
System: Linux version 4.9.0-4-amd64 running on amd64; UTF-8; en_GB (nb)
```

Comment: [1] What versions of JDK and Java EE are you using for your project? [2] It might be worth spending a couple of minutes creating a trivial _"Hello world"_ web project using the NetBeans wizard (**File > New Project... > Java Web > WebApplication**), and deploying it to WebLogic. If that fails at least you know that there is an issue with your NetBeans configuration, and/or WebLogic configuration, and you need to resolve that first.

Comment: @skomisa - that is what I have done, basically, and ther error I get indicates that it does not get as far as starting deplyoment, really. My impression is that it means something is missing on the server side, but I can't guess what. I have edited my question to add the versions.

Comment: OK. My thinking was that if you create a project using a wizard there is almost no possibility that it has any issues (not that I am implying your project does!). Since there is nothing in the server log, you could try looking in the NetBeans log (**View > IDE Log**) for any relevant errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the .war file was missing, just hit "Clean and Build Project" so that it gets deployed. It should run now, also a "Web Application" named as your project will appear in your server's admin console's "Deployments".